# saml/SSO error respond "HTTP 500 org.apache.xml.utils.URI$MalformedURIException"

Tags: spring-boot, single-sign-on, saml, adfs

I am integrating SSO with Spring boot. Here are some configuration insights

- my IDP (ADFS) service uses SAML 2.0.
- SP metadata is working correctly
- My application is redirecting to ADFS auth page.

The error appeared when the response is hitting the saml/SSO endpoint. It is like we're unable to handle correctly the response.

here is the error msg

```html
Type Exception Report

Message Filter execution threw an exception

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: Filter execution threw an exception
Root Cause

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/xml/utils/URI$MalformedURIException
    org.opensaml.xml.encryption.Decrypter.decryptKey(Decrypter.java:690)
    org.opensaml.xml.encryption.Decrypter.decryptKey(Decrypter.java:639)
    org.opensaml.xml.encryption.Decrypter.decryptUsingResolvedEncryptedKey(Decrypter.java:794)
    org.opensaml.xml.encryption.Decrypter.decryptDataToDOM(Decrypter.java:535)
    org.opensaml.xml.encryption.Decrypter.decryptDataToList(Decrypter.java:453)
    org.opensaml.xml.encryption.Decrypter.decryptData(Decrypter.java:414)
    org.opensaml.saml2.encryption.Decrypter.decryptData(Decrypter.java:141)
    org.opensaml.saml2.encryption.Decrypter.decrypt(Decrypter.java:69)
    org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.processAuthenticationResponse(WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.java:199)
    org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(SAMLAuthenticationProvider.java:88)
    org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:156)
    org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLProcessingFilter.attemptAuthentication(SAMLProcessingFilter.java:92)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:194)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:324)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:174)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:324)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:324)
    org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter.doFilter(ConcurrentSessionFilter.java:125)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:324)
    org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataGeneratorFilter.doFilter(MetadataGeneratorFilter.java:87)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:324)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:174)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
Root Cause

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.xml.utils.URI$MalformedURIException
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1955)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1798)
    org.opensaml.xml.encryption.Decrypter.decryptKey(Decrypter.java:690)
    org.opensaml.xml.encryption.Decrypter.decryptKey(Decrypter.java:639)
    org.opensaml.xml.encryption.Decrypter.decryptUsingResolvedEncryptedKey(Decrypter.java:794)
    org.opensaml.xml.encryption.Decrypter.decryptDataToDOM(Decrypter.java:535)
    org.opensaml.xml.encryption.Decrypter.decryptDataToList(Decrypter.java:453)
    org.opensaml.xml.encryption.Decrypter.decryptData(Decrypter.java:414)
    org.opensaml.saml2.encryption.Decrypter.decryptData(Decrypter.java:141)
    org.opensaml.saml2.encryption.Decrypter.decrypt(Decrypter.java:69)
    org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.processAuthenticationResponse(WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.java:199)
    org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(SAMLAuthenticationProvider.java:88)
    org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:156)
    org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLProcessingFilter.attemptAuthentication(SAMLProcessingFilter.java:92)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:194)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:324)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:174)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:324)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:324)
    org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter.doFilter(ConcurrentSessionFilter.java:125)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:324)
    org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataGeneratorFilter.doFilter(MetadataGeneratorFilter.java:87)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:324)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:174)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
Note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the server logs.
```

Here is my applicationContext.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd 
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.1.xsd 
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
                           http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/core 
                           http://jax-ws.java.net/spring/core.xsd
                           http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/servlet 
                           http://jax-ws.java.net/spring/servlet.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">


    <!-- Enable auto-wiring -->
    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="org.springframework.security.saml"/>

    <!-- BEGIN SAML CONFIGURATION -->

    <!-- Secured pages -->
    <security:http entry-point-ref="samlEntryPoint" access-denied-page="/login.htm?login_error=3">
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/metadata/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/login.htm*" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/requestAccess.htm*" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/css/*" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/js/*" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/images/*" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/resources/*" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/saml/metadata" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/favicon.ico" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/**/*" access="ROLE_CANCER APPLICATION - CRS PES COMMON"/>
        <!-- SP metadata should be generated during first request to the application  -->
        <security:custom-filter before="FIRST" ref="metadataGeneratorFilter"/>
        <security:custom-filter after="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" ref="samlFilter"/>
        
        <security:session-management session-fixation-protection="newSession" >
            <security:concurrency-control max-sessions="1" error-if-maximum-exceeded="false" />
        </security:session-management>
    </security:http>
    
    <bean id="samlFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy">
        <security:filter-chain-map request-matcher="ant">
            <security:filter-chain pattern="/saml/login/**" filters="samlEntryPoint"/>
            <security:filter-chain pattern="/saml/logout/**" filters="samlLogoutFilter"/>
            <security:filter-chain pattern="/saml/metadata/**" filters="metadataDisplayFilter"/>
            <security:filter-chain pattern="/saml/SSO/**" filters="samlWebSSOProcessingFilter"/>
            <security:filter-chain pattern="/saml/SSOHoK/**" filters="samlWebSSOHoKProcessingFilter"/>
            <security:filter-chain pattern="/saml/SingleLogout/**" filters="samlLogoutProcessingFilter"/>
            <security:filter-chain pattern="/saml/discovery/**" filters="samlIDPDiscovery"/>
        </security:filter-chain-map>
    </bean>

    <!-- Handler deciding where to redirect user after successful login -->
    <bean id="successRedirectHandler" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler">
        <property name="defaultTargetUrl" value="/OPERA/index.htm"/>

    </bean>


    <!-- Handler for successful logout -->
    <bean id="successLogoutHandler" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.SimpleUrlLogoutSuccessHandler">
        <property name="defaultTargetUrl" value="/OPERA/login.htm"/>
  
    </bean>

    <!-- Register authentication manager with SAML provider -->
    <security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <security:authentication-provider ref="samlAuthenticationProvider"/>
    </security:authentication-manager> 

    <!-- Logger for SAML messages and events -->
    <bean id="samlLogger" class="org.springframework.security.saml.log.SAMLDefaultLogger">
        <property name="logAllMessages" value="true"/>
        <property name="logErrors" value="true"/>
        <property name="logMessagesOnException" value="true"/>
    </bean>

    
    <!-- Central storage of cryptographic keys -->
    <bean id="keyManager" class="org.springframework.security.saml.key.JKSKeyManager">
        <constructor-arg value="file:C:/cert/tNeww.keystore"/>
        <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="password"/>
        <constructor-arg>
            <map>
                <entry key="alias" value="password"/>
                
            </map>
        </constructor-arg>
        <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="alias"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- Entry point to initialize authentication, default values taken from properties file -->
    <bean id="samlEntryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLEntryPoint">
        <property name="defaultProfileOptions">
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileOptions">
                <property name="includeScoping" value="false"/>
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- IDP Discovery Service -->
    <bean id="samlIDPDiscovery" class="org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLDiscovery">
        <property name="idpSelectionPath" value="/WEB-INF/idpSelection.jsp"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- Filter automatically generates default SP metadata -->
    <bean id="metadataGeneratorFilter" class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataGeneratorFilter">
        <constructor-arg>
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataGenerator">
                <property name="entityId" value="https://domain:443/OPERA"/>
                <property name="entityBaseURL" value="https://domain:443/OPERA"/>
                <property name="extendedMetadata">
                    <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.ExtendedMetadata">
                        <property name="signMetadata" value="false"/>
                        <property name="signingKey" value="alias"/> 
                        <property name="signingAlgorithm" value="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256"/>
                        <property name="digestMethodAlgorithm" value="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
                    </bean>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>
    
    <!-- Configure HTTP Client to accept certificates from the keystore for HTTPS verification -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.trust.httpclient.TLSProtocolConfigurer">
    </bean>
    
    <!-- The filter is waiting for connections on URL suffixed with filterSuffix and presents SP metadata there -->
    <bean id="metadataDisplayFilter" class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataDisplayFilter"/>

    <!-- IDP Metadata configuration - paths to metadata of IDPs in circle of trust is here -->
    <bean id="metadata" class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.CachingMetadataManager">
        <constructor-arg>
            <list>
                <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.ExtendedMetadataDelegate">
                    <constructor-arg>
                    
                        <bean class="org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.FilesystemMetadataProvider">
                            <constructor-arg>
                                <value type="java.io.File">file:C:/Metadata/idp-metadata2.xml</value>
                        </constructor-arg>
                            <property name="parserPool" ref="parserPool"/>
                        </bean>
                        

                    </constructor-arg>
                    <constructor-arg>
                        <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.ExtendedMetadata">
                                     </bean>
                    </constructor-arg>
                    <property name="metadataTrustCheck" value="false"/>
                </bean>
            </list>
        </constructor-arg>
        <!-- OPTIONAL used when one of the metadata files contains information about this service provider -->
        <!-- <property name="hostedSPName" value=""/> -->
        <!-- OPTIONAL property: can tell the system which IDP should be used for authenticating user by default. -->
        <!-- <property name="defaultIDP" value="urn:test:dag:dagtest"/> -->
    </bean>

    <!-- SAML Authentication Provider responsible for validating of received SAML messages -->
    <bean id="samlAuthenticationProvider" class="org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLAuthenticationProvider">
        <!-- OPTIONAL property: can be used to store/load user data after login -->
        <property name="userDetails" ref="userDetailsContextMapper" />
        <property name="forcePrincipalAsString" value="false"/>
    </bean>
    
    <bean id="userDetailsContextMapper" class="edu.umiami.ApprovalLoop.service.MyUserDetailsContextMapper">
        <property name="attributesToPopulate">
            <list>
                <value>cn</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        
        <property name="mapAllAttributes" value="true" />
        
        <property name="roleAttributes">
            <list>
                <value>ROLE</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <!-- <property name="rolePrefix" value="ROLE_" /> -->
    </bean>
    
    <!-- Configure the multipart resolver -->
    <bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
        <!-- one of the properties available; the maximum file size in bytes -->
        <property name="maxUploadSize" value="20000000" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Provider of default SAML Context -->
      <bean id="contextProvider" class="org.springframework.security.saml.context.SAMLContextProviderImpl">
        <property name="metadataResolver">
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.trust.MetadataCredentialResolver">
                <constructor-arg index="0" ref="metadata"/>
                <constructor-arg index="1" ref="keyManager"/>
                <property name="useXmlMetadata" value="true"/>
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>
    
    <!-- Processing filter for WebSSO profile messages -->
    <bean id="samlWebSSOProcessingFilter" class="org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLProcessingFilter">
        <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager"/>
        <property name="authenticationSuccessHandler" ref="successRedirectHandler"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- Processing filter for WebSSO Holder-of-Key profile -->
    <bean id="samlWebSSOHoKProcessingFilter" class="org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLWebSSOHoKProcessingFilter">
        <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager"/>
        <property name="authenticationSuccessHandler" ref="successRedirectHandler"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- Logout handler terminating local session -->
    <bean id="logoutHandler"
          class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.SecurityContextLogoutHandler">
        <property name="invalidateHttpSession" value="true"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- Override default logout processing filter with the one processing SAML messages -->
    <bean id="samlLogoutFilter" class="org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLLogoutFilter">
        <constructor-arg ref="successLogoutHandler"/>
        <constructor-arg ref="logoutHandler"/>
        <constructor-arg ref="logoutHandler"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- Filter processing incoming logout messages -->
    <!-- First argument determines URL user will be redirected to after successful global logout -->
    <bean id="samlLogoutProcessingFilter" class="org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLLogoutProcessingFilter">
        <constructor-arg ref="successLogoutHandler"/>
        <constructor-arg ref="logoutHandler"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- Class loading incoming SAML messages from httpRequest stream -->
    <bean id="processor" class="org.springframework.security.saml.processor.SAMLProcessorImpl">
        <constructor-arg>
            <list>
                <ref bean="redirectBinding"/>
                <ref bean="postBinding"/>
                <ref bean="artifactBinding"/>
                <ref bean="soapBinding"/>
                <ref bean="paosBinding"/>
            </list>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>

    <!-- SAML 2.0 WebSSO Assertion Consumer -->
    <bean id="webSSOprofileConsumer" class="org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl"> 
        <property name="maxAuthenticationAge" value="28800"/>  
    </bean>

    <!-- SAML 2.0 Holder-of-Key WebSSO Assertion Consumer -->
    <bean id="hokWebSSOprofileConsumer" class="org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileConsumerHoKImpl"/>

    <!-- SAML 2.0 Web SSO profile -->
    <bean id="webSSOprofile" class="org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileImpl"/>

    <!-- SAML 2.0 Holder-of-Key Web SSO profile -->
    <bean id="hokWebSSOProfile" class="org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileConsumerHoKImpl"/>

    <!-- SAML 2.0 ECP profile -->
    <bean id="ecpprofile" class="org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileECPImpl"/>

    <!-- SAML 2.0 Logout Profile -->
    <bean id="logoutprofile" class="org.springframework.security.saml.websso.SingleLogoutProfileImpl"/>

    <!-- Bindings, encoders and decoders used for creating and parsing messages -->
    <bean id="postBinding" class="org.springframework.security.saml.processor.HTTPPostBinding">
        <constructor-arg ref="parserPool"/>
        <constructor-arg ref="velocityEngine"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="redirectBinding" class="org.springframework.security.saml.processor.HTTPRedirectDeflateBinding">
        <constructor-arg ref="parserPool"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="artifactBinding" class="org.springframework.security.saml.processor.HTTPArtifactBinding">
        <constructor-arg ref="parserPool"/>
        <constructor-arg ref="velocityEngine"/>
        <constructor-arg>
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.websso.ArtifactResolutionProfileImpl">
                <constructor-arg>
                    <bean class="org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient"/>
                </constructor-arg>
                <property name="processor">
                    <bean id="soapProcessor" class="org.springframework.security.saml.processor.SAMLProcessorImpl">
                        <constructor-arg ref="soapBinding"/>
                    </bean>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>

    <bean id="soapBinding" class="org.springframework.security.saml.processor.HTTPSOAP11Binding">
        <constructor-arg ref="parserPool"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="paosBinding" class="org.springframework.security.saml.processor.HTTPPAOS11Binding">
        <constructor-arg ref="parserPool"/>
    </bean>
    
    <!-- <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLBootstrap" lazy-init="false"/> -->
    <bean class="edu.umiami.ApprovalLoop.service.CustomSAMLBootstrap" lazy-init="false"/>
    <bean id="velocityEngine" class="org.springframework.security.saml.util.VelocityFactory" factory-method="getEngine"/>
    <bean id="parserPool" class="org.opensaml.xml.parse.StaticBasicParserPool" init-method="initialize"/>
    <bean id="parserPoolHolder" class="org.springframework.security.saml.parser.ParserPoolHolder"/>
    
    <!-- END SAML CONFIGURATION -->

</beans>
```

I am using SAML Trace to check the request and the response

[Saml Trace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XSOA0.png)

Comment: I need to interpreted the error msg to continue debugging the error. I don't know where to start. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should add the xalan jar file to your deployment in the WEB-INF/lib directory so that it finds the org/apache/xml/utils within the classpath.